# How do I reorder group of <div> by clicking next and previous in jQuery

Tags: jquery

My goal is to create something like this:

(example)

1
2
3
4

if next is clicked

2
3
4
1

.. and clicked again

3
4
1
2

---

If previous is clicked

(example)

3
4
1
2

*previous clicked

2
3
4
1

Comment: Hello and welcome in StackOverflow. When u ask a question, it's better to give us your code. like that we can correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to approach this is to:

- turn that string into an array (using `split(' ')` )
- `splice` the element that is going to move. `splice()` cuts the element out of the array and returns an array of that cut element - which is why I am accessing it with [0]
- If we're adding that element to the beginning of the array, use `unshift()`, else use `push()`
- `join(' ')` the array back together into a string

We can figure out which button was clicked through a `data-attribute` - but there are other ways to do this as well.

More about: [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[data-dir]').click(function() {
    let data = $('.numbers').html().trim().split(' ');
    if ($(this).data('dir') === 'next') {
      n = data.splice(0, 1)[0];
      data.push(n);
    } else {
      n = data.splice(-1, 1)[0];
      data.unshift(n);
    }
    $('.numbers').html(data.join(' '));
  })
})
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-dir="prev">Prev</button><span class='numbers'>1 2 3 4</span><button data-dir="next">Next</button>
```